# Table width is extending beyond the page

Tags: tables, margins

Any suggestions my the table width is extending beyond the page.
The generated code is as follows:

```
      \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
       \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
       \usepackage{tabulary}
       \usepackage{tabularx}
       \usepackage{varioref}
       \usepackage{multirow}
       \usepackage{booktabs}
       \usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}  
       \usepackage{amsmath}
       \usepackage{amsthm} 
        \usepackage{mathpazo}
        \usepackage{eucal}
        \usepackage{mathrsfs}
        \usepackage{lmodern}
        \usepackage{cuted}
       \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
       \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
       \usepackage[english]{babel}
       \usepackage{graphicx}
       \usepackage{amssymb}
       \usepackage{mathtools}
       \usepackage{array}
      \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
      \usepackage[english]{babel}
       \usepackage{siunitx} 
       \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}                        
     \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
      \usepackage{rotating}
      \usepackage{siunitx}
      \usepackage{xparse,xstring} 
       \usepackage{varioref}  
    \usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
    \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} 
      \crefname{equation}{eq.}{eq.}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
       \DeclareRobustCommand{\variablename}[1]{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape #1}}\nolimits}
       \newcommand{\COVID}{\variablename{COVID\_19}}
       \newcommand{\China}{\variablename{F\_China}}
         \newcommand{\World}{\variablename{F\_World}}
        \newcommand{\ln}{\variablename{\ln}}
       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
       \def\Plus{\texttt{+}}
       \def\Minus{\texttt{-}}
          %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
        \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
             %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}
     \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
      \caption{Summary of Sign restrictions}
     \label{tab1}
     \begin{tabular}{l*{8}{c}}
    \toprule
    &F^{Ener}_{t}& F^{Prec_m}_{t}& F^{Ind_m}_{t}& F^{Agr}_{t}} & F^{Live_s}_{t}& 
    R^{\COVID}_{\substack{World}}& F^{China}_{j,t} & R^{\COVID}_{\substack{China}}   \\                
    \midrule
    Foreign Energy Price         &\Plus&\Plus&\Plus&\times&\times&\times&\times  \\               
    \midrule
    Foreign Precious metals Price& \Plus&\Plus&\Minus&\Minus&\Minus&\times&\times    \\
   \midrule
    Foreign Industrial metals Price   & \Plus&\Plus&\Minus&\Minus&\Minus&\times&\times    \\
    \midrule
     Foreign Agricultural Price   & \Plus&\Plus&\Minus&\Minus&\Minus&\times&\times    \\
  \midrule
  Foreign Livestock Price   & \Plus&\Plus&\Minus&\Minus&\Minus&\times&\times   \\
  \midrule
  World $R^{\COVID}_{\substack{World}}$    & \Plus&\Plus&\Minus&\Minus&\Minus&\times&\times   \\
   \midrule
   China Domestic factors    & \Plus&\Plus&\Minus&\Minus&\Minus&\times&\times    \\
  \midrule
  China $R^{\COVID}_{\substack{China}}$  & \Plus&\Plus&\Minus&\Minus&\Minus&\times&\times    \\ 
  \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

My Output:
[image]

Comment: Can you shorten the entries of the first column?

Comment: @leandriis it solves the problems but I want to have a more specific column, Thanks for the  clever suggestion

Comment: @leandriis maybe i could add "foreign" as footnote

Comment: add `\footnotesize` right after `\begin{table}[htbp]`

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the headers sideways. The `rotating` package provides an environment `\begin{sideways}...\end{sideways}`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand\sw[1]{\begin{sideways}$#1$\end{sideways}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\variablename}[1]{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape #1}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\COVID}{\variablename{COVID\_19}}
\def\Plus{\texttt{+}}
\def\Minus{\texttt{-}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l*{8}{c}}
  \toprule
  &\sw{F^{Ener}_{t}}& \sw{F^{Prec_m}_{t}}& \sw{F^{Ind_m}_{t}}& \sw{F^{Agr}_{t}}
  &\sw{F^{Live_s}_{t}}& \sw{R^{\COVID}_{\substack{World}}}& \sw{F^{China}_{j,t}} & \sw{R^{\COVID}_{\substack{China}}}   \\                
  \midrule
  Foreign Energy Price         &\Plus&\Plus&\Plus&$\times$&$\times$&$\times$&$\times$  \\               
  \midrule
  Foreign Precious metals Price& \Plus&\Plus&\Minus&\Minus&\Minus&$\times$&$\times$    \\
  \midrule
  Foreign Industrial metals Price   & \Plus&\Plus&\Minus&\Minus&\Minus&$\times$&$\times$    \\
  \midrule
  Foreign Agricultural Price   & \Plus&\Plus&\Minus&\Minus&\Minus&$\times$&$\times$    \\
  \midrule
  Foreign Livestock Price   & \Plus&\Plus&\Minus&\Minus&\Minus&$\times$&$\times$   \\
  \midrule
  World $R^{\COVID}_{\substack{World}}$    & \Plus&\Plus&\Minus&\Minus&\Minus&$\times$&$\times$   \\
  \midrule
  China Domestic factors    & \Plus&\Plus&\Minus&\Minus&\Minus&$\times$&$\times$    \\
  \midrule
  China $R^{\COVID}_{\substack{China}}$  & \Plus&\Plus&\Minus&\Minus&\Minus&$\times$&$\times$    \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An acceptable compromise could be:

```
        \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}m{90pt}*{8}{c}} % changed <<<
        \toprule
     & $F^{Ener}_{t}$ & $ F^{Prec_m}_{t}$ & $F^{Ind_m}_{t}$ & $ F^{Agr}_{t} $ & $ F^{Live_s}_{t}$ & $R^{\COVID}_{\substack{World}}$ & $ F^{China}_{j,t}$ & $ R^{\COVID}_{\substack{China}}$   \\                
        \midrule
        Foreign Energy Price & \Plus & \Plus & \Plus & \times & \times & \times & \times  \\               
        \midrule
        Foreign Precious metals Price & \Plus & \Plus & \Minus & \Minus & \Minus & \times & \times    \\
        \midrule
        Foreign Industrial metals Price & \Plus & \Plus & \Minus & \Minus & \Minus & \times & \times    \\
        \midrule
        Foreign Agricultural Price & \Plus & \Plus & \Minus & \Minus & \Minus & \times & \times    \\
        \midrule
        Foreign Livestock Price & \Plus & \Plus & \Minus & \Minus & \Minus & \times & \times   \\
        \midrule
        World $R^{\COVID}_{\substack{World}}$ & \Plus & \Plus & \Minus & \Minus & \Minus & \times & \times   \\
        \midrule
        China Domestic factors & \Plus & \Plus & \Minus & \Minus & \Minus & \times & \times    \\
        \midrule
        China $R^{\COVID}_{\substack{China}}$ & \Plus & \Plus & \Minus & \Minus & \Minus & \times & \times    \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
```

[image: out6]

(added `\def\times{\texttt{x}}` to preamble.)